# GZIP only compresses files when full file path specified - won't compress root

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, gzip, mod-deflate

If I include the following in my .htaccess, GZIP will only compress files when the full path to the file is specified:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

But the above rewrite is necessary to allow my CMS to function.

So for example:

https://karenkingston.co.uk isn't compressed, but https://karenkingston.co.uk/index.php is, and indeed https://karenkingston.co.uk/themes/coach/js/jquery.scripts.js also compresses.

PHP 7.2 but changing versions doesn't help. Nor does it help to enable GZIP from .htaccess vs. CPanel.

Here's the full .htaccess

```
Options -indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot 
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType application/x-font-woff2 .woff2
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff2 "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

ErrorDocument 404 /

Redirect 301 /home https://karenkingston.co.uk
Redirect 301 /search https://karenkingston.co.uk
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where/how have you implemented the GZIP compression? The `.htaccess` code you posted contains no such directives? What version of Apache are you using? How is PHP installed?

Comment: I'm still struggling to resolve this - GZIP is enabled in CPanel and is working correctly outside of the circumstances I've outlined above, where it doesn't compress anything at the root of a folder.

Answer (score 0):

the above code doesn't enable gzip use below code

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Comment: GZIP is enabled in CPanel and works fine where the full path is specified, but not at root.

Comment: @ColossalYouth mod_gzip.c auto takes the path of GZIP its Apache auto config thing

Answer (score 0):

do this in your .htaccess file

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xmlin
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

then in your php

```
<?php
   if (substr_count($_SERVER[‘HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING’], ‘gzip’))
   ob_start(“ob_gzhandler”);
   else ob_start();
?>
```

write the above php code in a file that is always active such as your config file or your index.php file